# How to send http request from Docker to localhost or Virtual Machine

Tags: http, docker, vagrant

Being new to Docker and VM's, I have run into a blocker. I have a node app that needs to send a `POST` request from a `Docker container` to a `Virtual Machine` or to my `local machine`.

I have read through the Docker documentation, but still don't understand what I need to do in order to accomplish this.

So how can I send an `http` request from my node app running in a `Docker Container` to my `Vagrant Box`?

Comment: Your question is about knowing how connecting to your host machine (or any virtual machine running on it), or how to do the request (for example using curl)?

Comment: The request is done in my node app using using the request module.

Comment: My question is about how allowing the request to go through from my Docker container to my host machine or any virtual machine running on it.

Comment: Hold up, a little confused.  Are you saying you have a docker instance on your host machine and you are trying to get your node app (in the docker instance) to talk to something on a virtual machine (also on you host machine)?

Comment: Yes. I figured it out anyway. I just RTFM again. I just added the -P flag when running the docker image to bind the specified port to all interfaces on the host machine.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Docker creates a virtual interface (`docker0`) in your host machine with IP 172.17.42.1. Each of the container launched will have an IP of the network 172.17.42.1/16, and they will be able to connect to host machine connecting to IP 172.17.42.1.

If you want to connect a docker container with another service running in a virtual machine running with other provider (e.g.: virtualbox, vmware), the easiest way is forwarding the ports needed by the service to you host machine and then, from your docker container, connecting to IP 172.17.42.1. You should check your virtual machine provider documentation to see details about this. And if you are using libvirt/KVM (or with any other provider), you can use iptables to enable port forwarding.